# photoshop make selection by coords

Tags: selector, photoshop

In Adobe Photoshop, having rectangle coords, how do I make selection box in my image?
For instance, I have x = 100, y = 200, w = 80, h = 40.
Is there any way to specify these coords in some edit boxes and get marching ants selection?

Comment: If this is about using Photoshop and not developing a Photoshop plugin, you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make 4 guides at these locations (have the 'info' viewport open).

To make a guide, have the ruler (ctrl+r) viewing, use something like the Move tool (V), and click on the ruler and drag outwards to the page. A thin blue line (guide) will come up. Drag this to one of the edges of the box you are needing (you might need to zoom in to get fine control).

Click and drag from the left ruler for a vertical guide, and from the top ruler for a horizontal guide (or hold down ALT key to change it, when clicking + holding).

After these are setup, you can use the rectangular marquee tool (M) to do your selection. It will snap to the guides.

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan for your effort. It works great for me. However, I'm looking for a "digital-only" method. I mean without using mouse. That's why I'm marking your answer as useful, but not accepted.